# Companion to theoretical physics for working mathematicians

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, mp.mathematical-physics, physics

In the Princeton Companion to Mathematics one reads that even pure mathematicians should know some theoretical physics and applied mathematics. What are some well-organized comprehensive companions to theoretical physics for working mathematicians? I have heard of Armin Wachter and Henning Hoeber's, but I don't know if it is rigorous enough (i.e., for example, there are enough proofs of the theorem given).

Comment: There are many areas of physics. Surely some are more pertinent/relevant to mathematicians than others. Hopefully someone answering keeps this in mind in their recommendations.

Comment: The idea that one book could be a comprehensive companion to any well-established academic field strikes me as a bit far-fetched.

Comment: And yet there exists a Princeton Companion to Mathematics.

Comment: Gerard 't Hooft has a web page aimed at giving guidance to those teaching themselves physics. It has some lists of good books. http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~Gadda001/goodtheorist/index.html

Comment: @Allen: Yes, but no Princeton *Comprehensive* Companion to Mathematics.  (Perhaps I am taking that one word too seriously...)

Comment: See also https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/10297/376 on Mathematics Educators

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you allow such a comprehensive reference to re-introduce basic mathematics, then either as a layman or a working mathematician your prayers are answered by the following (he even prefaces by saying that his intended layman-audience must have some mathematical sophistication):

> **The Road to Reality: A Complete Guide to the Laws of the Universe**, by Roger Penrose

Now let's try to break down the subjects.

Classical Mechanics:
1) **Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics**, by Arnold
2) **A Mathematical Introduction to Fluid Mechanics**, by Chorin-Marsden

Quantum Mechanics:
1) **Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics**, by Mackey
2) **The Theory of Groups and Quantum Mechanics**, by Weyl

General Relativity:
1) **General Relativity for Mathematicians**, by Sachs-Wu
2) **The Large Scale Structure of Space-Time**, by Hawking-Ellis

Electrodynamics:
1) **Electromagnetic Theory and Computation: A Topological Approach**, by Gross-Kotiuga
2) **On the Mathematical Foundations of Electrical Circuit Theory**, by Smale
3) This is a plug for Gauge theory:
3a) **On Some Recent Developments in Yang-Mills Theory**, by Bott
3b) **On Some Recent Interactions Between Mathematics and Physics**, by Bott
3c)  **Concept of Nonintegrable Phase Factors and Global Formulation of Gauge Fields**, by Wu-Yang
3d) **From Superconductors and Four-Manifolds to Weak Interactions**, by Witten

Standard Model:
**The Algebra of Grand Unified Theories**, by Baez-Huerta

Quantum Field Theory and String Theory:
1) **Quantum Physics: A Functional Integral Point of View**, by Jaffe-Glimm
2) **Geometry and Quantum Field Theory**, 1994 IAS lectures
3) **Quantum Fields and Strings: A Course for Mathematicians**, 1996 IAS lectures

Comment: Can you give some references to Bott's papers?

Comment: +1 for recommending Roger Penrose. _Road to Reality_ is a great start to understanding physics from a mathematical perspective. Penrose starts from the foundation of numbers and by the end goes to twistor theory.

Comment: Great list. As of 2022, I would also add Wald's Advanced Classical Electromagnetism.

Answer (score 8):

If you are not interested too much in details, the following book can play  the role of a comprehensive companion: [http://www.amazon.com/Unified-Grand-Theoretical-Physics-Edition/dp/1439884463](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439884463) (A Unified Grand Tour of Theoretical Physics, by Ian D. Lawrie).

Truly comprehensive systematic introduction to theoretical physics can be found in the (many-volume) well known "Course of Theoretical Physics" by Landau and
Lifshitz: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_of_Theoretical_Physics
as well as in the more contemporary German counterpart by Walter Greiner:  http://onphysicsbooks.blogspot.ru/2009/01/walter-greiner.html

Answer (score 6):

The answer to this question depends sensitively on how much physics you want to learn.

For a brief overview of all of physics, two good choices are [The Six Core Theories of Modern Physics](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/six-core-theories-modern-physics) by Charles Stevens and [The Theoretical Minimum](http://theoreticalminimum.com/) by Leonard Susskind.

If you want to delve more deeply then I think it is best to go for a book that treats just one subfield of physics, such as classical mechanics or quantum field theory.  Some good suggestions are listed in the related [Physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6047/physics-for-mathematicians) question.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Physics and Partial Differential Equations, by Tatsien Li and Tiehu Qin, published by SIAM.

Answer (score 2):

Try Eberhard Zeidler's multi-volume *Quantum Field Theory*. This is extremely comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

To give a partial answer: this is a nice companion to quantum physics for mathematicians (especially those that are into category theory and/or operator algebras): [Deep Beauty: Understanding the Quantum World through Mathematical Innovation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107005701), ed Hans Halvorson.