# Mathematical physics roadmap

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, books, online-resources

I am looking for a roadmap to be able to understand more of the physical theory behind mathematical physics (at the level where I can read physics oriented textbooks/monographs)

I have a background in manifolds, some riemannian geometry, algebraic geometry (mostly hartshorne I and II but also some of III), complex algebraic geometry, hodge theory, algebraic topology, graduate analysis, etc. (some other basic grad courses)
But not k-theory or representation theory.

I’ve been reading chapter 1 of nakahara. I don’t know EM or QM and am reading on GR. I’m not sure if this would suffice. I was also thinking of reading the *part 2* section of the clays book on mirror symmetry.
I should also clarify that I’m not trying to achieve a mastery of modern physics.

Comment: This MO question has an extensive list of pointers: https://mathoverflow.net/q/191609/11260

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Companion to theoretical physics for working mathematicians](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191609/companion-to-theoretical-physics-for-working-mathematicians)